# Multiple csla:InvokeMethods on a Control

Tags: csla

How do you set multiple csla:InvokeMethods on a control?

for example a csla:InvokeMethod.TriggerEvent for  the click event and one for the MouseEnter event of a button?

This obviously won't work

csla:InvokeMethod.TriggerEvent="Click"

csla:InvokeMethod.MethodName = "OnClickHandler"

csla:invokeMethod.TriggerEvent="MouseEnter"

csla:InvokeMethod.MethodName = "OnMouseEnterHandler"/>

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found here:

http://forums.lhotka.net/forums/p/8557/40780.aspx#40780